# After boot go automatically to graphical login screen

Tags: 18.04, login, login-screen, lxde

I installed `Ubuntu 18.04.6 desktop` and then `lubuntu-desktop`.
Now the system boots to non-graphical login screen. The user of the laptop
will have to press `ctrl+alt+F7` to go to graphical login screen.

Is there some configuration file where I can set it to go automatically to graphical
login screen?

Comment: @guiverc see the edit.

Comment: Which dm (display manager) did you select to use?  Ubuntu desktop (GNOME) defaults to `gdm3` which is not used by LXDE/Lubuntu so you would have been asked to select one to use (the display manager is the greeter or login screen).

Comment: @guiverc I'm using LXDM

Comment: Have you tried using the LXDE/Lubuntu default; which was `lightdm`?  ie. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and you should be asked to re-select one of the DMs   (note: this is from memory as we've not supported LXDE for awhile.. but https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/ matches my memory... I recall some testing with `lxdm` & others (`xdm`) in 2019/2020 but too long ago)  Lubuntu included a GUI config tool for `lightdm` - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/lubuntu-desktop

Comment: I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, but after login the user has Ubuntu desktop (Unity I think), but he needs some lightweight desktop. That's because I'm using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lxdm`

Comment: Unity wasn't a default on any release from 17.10 onwards; as 17.04 was the last Ubuntu release that had Unity 7 installed by default; so it's probably GNOME thus `gdm3` I mentioned earlier (Unity 7 defaulted to `lightdm` like LXDE/Lubuntu did).   The option for `dpkg-reconfigure` doesn't matter as you're asked to select one; you just have to give a package that is installed; but I'd not expect (*recollection here only*) `lxdm` to be installed by a `apt install lubuntu-desktop` for *bionic*

Comment: You select the desktop you want to use at login; you can use a particularly desktop, or use the one selected in the prior login session (ie. once you switch from GNOME or Ubuntu desktop to LXDE/Lubuntu desktop - it'll default to LXDE/Lubuntu desktop).   Lubuntu includes a number of options (eg. LXDE is WM agnostic & Lubuntu uses `openbox` thus we give `openbox` as an option without LXDE - but I forget what's offered & won't load a system up as LXDE/Lubuntu 18.04 is EOL)

Comment: @guiverc For me it would be OK to always press `ctrl+alt+F7`, but my old coworker which wanted to try Ubuntu, it's little bad to tell her that she always has to press `ctrl+alt+F7` when she wants to login

Comment: I realize your issue (*I've seen it in testing I believe*), but Lubuntu no longer support LXDE or 18.04, so I'm unwilling to explore to work out what I'm vaguely remembering... my oldest Lubuntu *testing* setup is 20.04; as that's the oldest release we currently support.  You'll have to wait for others.  Some of my questions/queries are geared at getting you help from others (details you give that aren't expected; at least by me that has a *fair* experience with LXDE/Lubuntu even if not that recent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to install gdm3, because it is robust and works with practically everything. Then, choose it as the default display manager.

`sudo apt install gdm3 && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

the command will install `gdm3` and then bring up a screen to choose a default display manager. Please choose `gdm3`

Reboot, and you should get a gui login screen.

You can do it! I have faith in you!

Comment: I already put the laptop back to my coworker and learned her to press `ctrl+alt+F7`, but when I visit her again, I will certainly try it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to (re)install special Lubuntu Desktop task package by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop^
```

In the above command note `^` at the end, it is task. It will install all the packages which Lubuntu installation has out the box.

Then reboot.